# iOS webview viewpoint scaling under 1.0?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

On my webpage I have:

```
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.80, maximum-scale=0.80, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
```

This works fine for everything I've tested including safari on a iPhone but it refuses to scale to anything less then 1.0 inside of a webview in a iOS app.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
[_mywebview setScalesPageToFit:true];
```

fixes it for some reason.